# How to load Spinners by Json within AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-spinner

Im new to Android Development. I want to fill spinner by Json array which load from the Http request(by AsyncTask). My AsyncTask in seperate class called Load_spinnrs. I to do this?

here is my http request

```
try{

    String DataSendingTo="http://www.mysite.com/AppRequest/load_data";

    //HttpClient
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    //Post header
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(DataSendingTo);


    //Adding data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("authorized","001"));



    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    // execute HTTP post request
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);


    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
        builder.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(builder.toString());
    JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);


   //How to load Spinner ?????



} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: Go to this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174065/populating-spinner-with-json-in-android-4-2-using-asynctask?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174065/populating-spinner-with-json-in-android-4-2-using-asynctask?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

After you get array of `JSON`

You have to do like:

```
final String[] items = new String[jsonArray.length()]; 

// looping through All Contacts
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

    JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    // Storing each json item in variable

    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);


    items[i]=c.getString(TAG_NAME);
    System.out.println("Hello events "+items);
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);       

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

sp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

### [Populate an Android Spinner with JSON data from a RESTful web API](http://cyriltata.blogspot.in/2013/01/populate-android-spinner-with-json-data.html)

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items); 

gives "The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(RequestSend, int, String[]) is undefined"

Comment: Change `YourActvity.this` instead of `this`

Comment: When set sp.setAdapter(adapter); error occurs "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Comment: Put Log tags after every lines so you get understand where is your problem exactly, try to get `adapter.getCount();`

Answer (score 1):

If you are extending `AsyncTask` in separate class then you will need to pass Activity context from which you are executing extending for accessing UI elements in on normal java class. for this you can use `Load_spinnrs` class constructor to get Activity context and use `onPostExecute` for accessing Spinner as:

```
class  Load_spinnrs extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
Activity activity;
Context context;
public Load_spinnrs(Activity activity,Context context){
 this.activity=activity;
 this.context=context;
}
...
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     //access UI elements here..
     Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)activity.findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);   
     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (context, 
                             android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
     //....  
     super.onPostExecute(result);
  }

}
```

For pass Context start  AsyncTask  as from Activity:

```
 Load_spinnrs load_spin=new Load_spinnrs(this,this);
 load_spin.execute(parameters);
```

Comment: @SajithaRathnayake : Activity. to pass Activity context start AsyncTask as `new Load_spinnrs(this).execute("")`

Comment: I think you have to initialize every UI Element in `onCreate()` and then you can use their objects in `AsyncTask`

Comment: (String result) What the result would be?

Comment: @SajithaRathnayake: becuase useing AsyncTask see [here] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) why we have methods and different parameters meaning.

Comment: So how do i return Json Array to onPostExecute?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this may be help you:

```
 GetServerData.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {

     // Server Request URL
     String serverURL = "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/getPage.php";

     // Create Object and call AsyncTask execute Method
     new LongOperation().execute(serverURL);

 }
});  

    protected void onPreExecute() {
      // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

      //UI Element
      uiUpdate.setText("Output : ");
      Dialog.setMessage("Downloading source..");
      Dialog.show();
 }
```

for more details you have :

http://androidexample.com/AsyncroTask_Example_To_Get_Server_Data_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=59&aaid=84

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/12/android-populating-spinner-data-from-mysql-database/

Best regards

Comment: You didn't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

for easily understand, Load your Load_spinnrs class as, sub class of your main class.

for example;

```
public class Main_Class extends Activity
{

private Spinner spinner;
       protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.userprofiles);
 //init spinner here

    }

private class Load_spinnrs extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
// your http request
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
//update spinner here.
}


}
```

Comment: my AsyncTask is ok. I want to load spinner from AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation in the AsyncTask to show the loading spinner and then dismiss it when the AsyncTask is complete.

```
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        <put code here>
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
                }

}

}
```